# Uninstall program from Remote Computer

Tags: powershell

I'd like to uninstall a program from a remote computer. I know the location of the MSI that was used for the install, it's on the remote server and the path can be seen in the variable `$MSIPathFile` below.

When I run the following script:

```
$TargetServer = "d-vasbiz01"
$MSIPathFile = "c:\biztalkdeployment\x.Int.MIS-3.0.0.msi"

Invoke-Command -Computer $TargetServer -ScriptBlock {Param($MSIPathFile, $UninstallFlag, $QuietFlag) Start-Process msiexec.exe "/x" $MSIPathFile "/qn"} -ArgumentList "$MSIPathFile", "/x", "/qn"
```

I get the following error:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $TargetServer -ScriptBlock {Param($MSIPathFile, $UninstallFlag, $QuietFlag) Start-Process msiexec.exe "/x" $MSIPathFile "/qn"} -ArgumentList "$MSIPathFile", "/x", "/qn"
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'c:\biztalkdeployment\x.Int.MIS-3.0.0.msi'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really an answer to my question but it solves my problem of remotely uninstalling an MSI. I hope this can help someone else as I've spent the last 3 hours trying various techniques!

It turns out this can be achieved with a single line of code!

(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name='x.Int.MIS for BizTalk 2010 3.0.0'" -ComputerName $TargetServer ).Uninstall()

Courtesy of the following technet page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347651.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late edit by pc crashed as I was replying so it half updated.

The problem is that the start Start-Process does not seem to expand the variable and execute it with the command. So what I do to get it to work is build up a string containing path to the executable and then another to parameters I would like to use. I then use the Invoke-expression command to execute it .
Here is an example below if you like I can edit your code ,but I thought you might like an example and explanation.

```
$MSIPathFile = "c:\biztalkdeployment\x.Int.MIS-3.0.0.msi"


$msiexec = "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe"
$arguments = '/x' + $MSIPathFile + " /qn"
Invoke-Expression  -Command "$msiexec $arguments"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer justif but I found an alternative solution to my wider problem

Comment: this will explain why it did not work,I had the same problem and ended up doing this.